# export FLASK_APP=./index.py invalid syntax

Tags: bash, flask

Getting a syntax error on when I run this as a bash file, here is code:

```
#!/bin/bash
export FLASK_APP=./index
source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate
flask run -h 0.0.0.0
```

The error is:

```
 python bootstrap.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ─╯
  File "bootstrap.sh", line 2
    export FLASK_APP=./index
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This runs fine on my linux box, but is giving me a syntax error running on my work mac. I can run the command in the shell fine, what am I doing wrong that won't allow this to run from a bash script?

Comment: The reason why you add the shebang (`#!`) is to avoid having to invoke `interpreter script` and run just `script` (assuming permissions are fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to run the shell script with python?

`python bootstrap.sh`

Run it with shell instead:

`$ sh bootstrap.sh` or `$ ./bootstrap.sh`

Comment: Thankyou Sir, yes it seems I did on this occasion, I've no idea why other than habit and muscle memory, I now understand the downvote, shame the person could not have just commented as well, I've not met anyone yet that does not make silly mistakes.